# What is this notation called?

Tags: java

Class names can be abbreviated as follows:

```
CustomerService => CS
CustomerPaymentService => CPS
UnpaidBillRetriever => UBR
FindAnyRemainingOpenUserTrasactions => FAROUT
```

This is supported by control-N (idea) or control-shift-T (eclipse). After some initial re-learning I now use this naming strategy heavily. But what is it called ?

Comment: Do you mean the "open type" functionality?

Comment: In eclipse, yes. Go to class in idea

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused. Is this a compilable java language expression? Perhaps if you could add an example usage of it in a class. Had a look through the Java Language spec and couldn't find anything. It looks a bit like what in C/C++ you would call a typedef.

Comment: @Evan It's not compilable java. It's used to navigate the code in eclipse/idea and is excellent if you have a large code base with lots of long class names.

Comment: Ah, pity. I was getting a little excited there - I've always thought Java could badly use a typedef-like feature. Would be fantastic to crunch something ridiculous like "HashMap<String, ArrayList<MyStuff>>" to something with a more meaningful context.

Comment: @Evan - As an aside Groovy has added an aliasing feature for imports
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Static+Import+Usage 
import static com.some.package.SomeAnnoyinglyNamedException as SANE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Camel-Case. Since you would only take the upper letters.

Comment: boutta is right, most people call it "Camel-Case matching".  I don't think it has another name.

Comment: "Camel-case matching" sounds sensible,it's a verb and actually the best one yet. Not *exactly* what boutta said but I may be nitpicking

Comment: Even in the Eclipse documentation it's called that way. I haven't found a ref yet, but it's the only name I know.

Answer (score 3):

I would call it an acronym.

Comment: Sorry to be a pedant, but see http://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/acronym. Acronyms are said as a word: Laser, NASA, Scuba are acronyms; CS, CPS, UBR are just abbreviations.

Comment: And its quite confusing that TLA (Three Letter Acronym) is NOT an acroynm itself.

Comment: @toolkit: I agree, and it is an important distinction in HTML (acronyms can be pronounced while abbrs must be spelled out by voice readers). Although strictly speaking, I think USB or TLA (Three Letter Abbreviations) are initialisms (which are a subset of abbrevs).

Comment: And don't forget that you can also have an ETLA.

Comment: @PhiLho - yep, should have said initialisms
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Letter_Acronym

Answer (score 0):

May be 'alias'?